# Tomcat Hot Deplot works fine for JSP Files But not for Java Files

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

Due to performance Issues in my PC, I am not using the standard route of Eclipse-Tomcat-Maven Integration. What I do is build my changes using Maven and then manually copy the files to Tomcat webapps folder.

Whenever I copy the JSP files to the webapps folder I can see the changes are reflected. However for class files, the changes are not at all reflected.

I am only making minor changes within the methods of my class(adding a sysout, or delete a line of code etc) and not making any structural changes.

In my server.xml I can see autodeploy and deployonstartup set to true.

```
 <Engine defaultHost="localhost" name="Catalina" jvmRoute="tomcat01" debug="0">
 <Host appBase="webapps" name="localhost" autoDeploy="true" 
     deployOnStartup="true" unpackWARs="true" deployXML="true">
```

Tomcat version is Apache Tomcat/6.0.29

Please can anybody tell me what might be going wrong ?

Comment: don't you use war deployment/redeployment? only change the jsps?

Comment: Yes I do. But when I am changing just a single java file, I feel it is better to go for a manual update of class file rather than redeploy the whole war. My assumption is that the hot deploy should detect changes when I move an updated class file to the webapps folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading tomcat6 [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html) and the part `Deploying on a running Tomcat server`, it states on the last line:

> Note that web application reloading can also be configured in the loader, in which case loaded classes will be tracked for changes.

Therefore going to the loader [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/loader.html) you can see that setting the attribute `reloadable` of your loader configuration will do exactly what you are asking

> reloadable: Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is very useful during application development, but it requires significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on deployed production applications. You can use the Manager web application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand. NOTE - The value for this property will be inherited from the reloadable attribute you set on the surrounding Context component, and any value you explicitly set here will be replaced.